# Java Selenium 3.5.3 -Invalid moz:firefoxOptions field members

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

**After Selenium up-gradation getting these error.**

### System

- Version: geckodriver-v0.18.0
- Platform: Linux/ubuntu 1704
- Firefox: Firefox 55.0.3
- Selenium: 3.5.3

### Stacktrace

```
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: Exception in thread "main
> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Invalid
> moz:firefoxOptions field members Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Build
> info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' Sep 18
> 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: System info: host: 'costcoscraper-instance', ip:
> '10.0.98.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
> '4.10.0-32-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Driver
> info: driver.version: Fi"refoxDriver Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: remote
> stacktrace: stack backtrace: Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance
> startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:    0:           0x5787ed -
> backtrace::backtrace::trace::h59229d13f6a8837d Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:    1: 
> 0x578942 - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::h23089c033eded8f0 Sep
> 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url:    2:           0x4463cc -
> webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::hd11f864b1fdf4510 Sep 18
> 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url:    3:           0x440ff3 - <core::iter::Map<I, F>
> as core::iter::iterator::Iterator>::next::h4f3cf544297176b2 Sep 18
> 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url:    4:           0x44baa3 -
> geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::h6f7058fccafe4367
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url:    5:           0x425c32 -
> <webdriver::server::Dispatcher<T, U>>::run::h8f5348b8f5f7c053 Sep 18
> 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url:    6:           0x40b22c -
> std::panicking::try::do_call::hb67c6fb6bcd96195 Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:    7: 
> 0x5dc20a - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:       
> at /checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:98 Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:    8: 
> 0x41b943 - <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box::h4100941edc372034
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url:    9:           0x5d48a4 -
> alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()> Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:       
> at /checkout/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:650 Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:       
> - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:       
> at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21 Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:       
> - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:       
> at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84 Sep 18 06:51:54
> costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: #011at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) Sep 18
> 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$24(ProtocolHandshake.java:359)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:362)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:255)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:237)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:138)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
> Sep 18 06:51:54 costcoscraper-instance startup-script: INFO
> startup-script-url: #011at
> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
```

Please  help to resolve this issue. getting this problem after upgrading the selenium version and geckodriver and firefox.

This updated code for selenium 3.5.3 to run the firefox in headless mode.

```
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/karanpal_insonix/geckodriver");
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
Firefox driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

To initiate **`Mozilla Firefox`** in **`Headless Mode`** you need to use the **`FirefoxOptions`** class and pass the **`--headless`** argument and the absolute path of the **`firefox`** binary i.e. **`firefox.exe`**. It's worth to mention that **`Mozilla Firefox Headless Mode`** is still in `Development Stage` and the functionality is available in **`Mozilla Nightly Build`** only. Here is the sample code block:

```
package firefox;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

public class headless {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Nightly\\firefox.exe");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        System.out.println("Firefox Headless Browser Invoked");
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Here you can have a detailed view of [**`Mozilla Firefox in Headless Mode through Selenium 3.5.2 (Java)`**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPS89xCgNhk&feature=youtu.be)